From GIMP, how to store images losslessly at maximum compression when creating a PDF?
Assume an image opened in GIMP in Debian 12. From this image, you would like to create a single-page PDF file with maximum lossless compression.  How?  As of 2024-12-19, https://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-images-out.html doesn't mention PDF at all.  Besides GIMP, you have standard Linux tools at your disposal, including ImageMagick.

Gimp's PDF export (as of current GIMP versions for the last couple of years at least) uses the Cairo library's PDF writer, and hands it lossless image data, which that then puts in a FLATE-Compressed (which is lossless, and not very high-compression for images) stream inside the PDF.
So, no need to do anything special. GIMP already does almost what you want when you just export an image to a PDF.
There's nothing really adjustable about the compression ratio; while you can increase the compression effort in some PDF writers (but for the cairo PDF surface, and hence also not in GIMP), the compression used is almost as good as it's going to get with FLATE, and FLATE is, as far as FOSS software is concerned, the best-compressing lossless image encoder.
There's more than FLATE for lossless image compression in PDFs – but for color images, that is restricted to strictly worse compression algorithms (RLE, and a less advanced LZW). There's also the JPEG2000 format, which has a lossless compression mode. That does have better compression than FLATE (for most types of image data), but encoders are rare (many builds of ImageMagick don't support it, though that might have changed in the last couple of years as license/patenting around that image format has cleared up).

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
